# Give an example for an unbounded $f:(1,2) \to \mathbb{R}$, which is continuously differentiable in $(1,2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Give an example for an unbounded $f:(1,2) \to \mathbb{R}$, which is
>   continuously differentiable in $(1,2)$

Can you find an example? I been trying to construct a rational expression, but I am failing.

Comment: $\frac1{(x-1)(x-2}$, for instance.

Comment: Does it have to be a rational function?  What about something based on the tangent function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the function $f(x)={1\over{x-2}}$